# Can type size change between compile time and runtime?

Tags: c

Let say I have a platform P<sub>A</sub> (with a compiler) where `int` is 16 bits and a platform P<sub>B</sub> (with a compiler) where `int` is 32 bits.
Now let consider the following code:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%u %zu\n", UINT_MAX, sizeof(unsigned int));
    return 0;
}
```

I then compile the program on P<sub>A</sub> get the executable E<sub>A</sub>, and I also compile the program on P<sub>B</sub> to get the executable E<sub>B</sub>.

If I run E<sub>A</sub> on P<sub>A</sub> I will get:

```
65535 2
```

If I run E<sub>B</sub> on P<sub>B</sub> I will get:

```
4294967295 4
```

Now, what happen if I run E<sub>A</sub> on P<sub>B</sub>? Will it run? If so what will be the output?

```
65535 2
```

because the program was compiled on a platform where `int` is 16 bits, or

```
65535 4
```

because now `int` is 32 bits (`65535` can't change because it's evaluated at compile time, at least it's what I understood).

If it's the last option that happen, can we trust macros defined in `limit.h`?

Comment: That is how static types work. Also, that is how binary programs work.

Comment: With `"%u %zu"` And macros are expanded at compile-time.

Comment: "a platform PB where int is 32 bits. " conflagrates the _compiler_ with the _platform_.   The compiler is  using `int` as 32-bit.  The executable it makes runs with that behavior.  If the executable runs on different platforms, it is still 32-bit.

Comment: `ow, what happen if I run EA on PB?` any combination of funny things. Depending on what `PlatformA` and `PlatformB` mean, the code might refuse to run with meaningful message, run as expected (if platforms are compatible, and provisions are made on one platform to execute code targeted for another), run and crash (if incompatible native code is run and triggered bad instruction), run and give you the next jackpot Powerball winning combination (that would be somewhat on the rare side, and usually only in case of extreme luck).

Comment: @Cl00e9ment The sizeof operator in this case and UINT_MAX are evaluated at compile time and will be stored in an object file as is.

Comment: OK I made some corrections to my question according to your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, what happen if I run E<sub>A</sub> on P<sub>B</sub>? Will it run?

In general, no; in general random different platforms aren't compatible, for IA differences (e.g. an x86 processor doesn't know how to run ARM machine code), executable format differences (e.g. the macOS loader doesn't know what to do with Linux ELF executables) and runtime environment differences.

There are some specific combinations that can work, though; a very common case is 32-bit x86 executables running on a 64-bit x86_64 (AKA x86 AKA amd64) processor. This is generally subject to the fact that the OS does some compatibility work for the runtime part, but most importantly because the processor has a "32 bit compatibility mode", in which it behaves essentially as an "old style" 32 bit processor. So, it's not like this runtime property has changed - the 64 bit processor fakes being a 32 bit one.

> If so what will be the output?

```
65535 2
```

because types in C are resolved at compile time, and the executable code has been written to manipulate 16 bit words.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's really clear!

Answer (score 2):

Supplementing the previous answer, it should be mentioned that the size of C data types, e.g. `int` is not a property determined by the platform, but a property determined by the compiler. Of course, the compiler must comply with the constraints of the platform and the rules of the C language. A compiler supporting different platforms could also implement different sizes of an `int`, depending on the selected target platform. A compiler could even offer an option to select between different `int` sizes for the same platform. However, in all cases the size of `int` is decided by the compiler at the time of compilation.

Thus definitions in e.g. `limit.h` would be made dependent on the chosen platform and other compiler options affecting the definitions.

For your example this means that `UINT_MAX` and `sizeof(unsigned int)` are substituted by their respective values at compile time. So wherever a given version of the compiled code is run, the output will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: +1, that's something I wanted to add but I forgot. In general, the mapping between C types and hardware types can be arbitrary, but once an executable is compiled it's effectively written in stone. IOW, regardless of whether my compiler calls it `int` or your call it `long`, if they both are 32 bit and target the same platform the generated code for both will manipulate the same underlying hardware type.